Entering Attributes of a Class into a Pandas Dataframe
I have a class named Entry which has these attributes;
Column, Task, Description, Assigned Member, Timeline
Each attribute stores a string.
I would like to enter each attribute in each row of the dataframe.
The Column Attribute of Entry is used to identify the column of the same name to which the entry belongs, while the rest of the attributes are entered into the dataframe.
The issue I am having is that whenever I add a new entry that belongs to a new column, it goes into an index after the previous entry that belongs to a different column. I would like to ensure that each new entry goes into the next available rows for that column.
The Erroneous Output looks like this;



index
column 1
column 2
column 3
column 4




0
Task: text
NaN
NaN
NaN


1
Description: text
NaN
NaN
NaN


2
Assigned Member: text
NaN
NaN
NaN


3
Timeline: text
NaN
NaN
NaN


4
NaN
Task: text
NaN
NaN


5
NaN
Description: text
NaN
NaN


6
NaN
Assigned Member: text
NaN
NaN


7
NaN
Timeline: text
NaN
NaN


8
NaN
NaN
Task: text
NaN


9
NaN
NaN
Description: text
NaN


10
NaN
NaN
Assigned Member: text
NaN


11
NaN
NaN
Timeline: text
NaN


12
NaN
NaN
NaN
Task: text


13
NaN
NaN
NaN
Description: text


14
NaN
NaN
NaN
Assigned Member: text


15
NaN
NaN
NaN
Timeline: text



Here is my initial implementation,
import pandas as pd

class Entry:
    def __init__(self, column, task, desc, member, timeline):
        self.column = column
        self.task = f"Task: {task}"
        self.desc = f"Description: {desc}"
        self.member = f"Assigned Member: {member}"
        self.timeline = f"Timeline: {timeline}"
        
#Add each attribute of the entry to the dataframe, use the c attribute as the column name, place each attribute in it's own row
def enter_entries(df, entries):
    for entry in entries:
        df = df._append({entry.column: entry.task}, ignore_index=True)
        df = df._append({entry.column: entry.desc}, ignore_index=True)
        df = df._append({entry.column: entry.member}, ignore_index=True)
        df = df._append({entry.column: entry.timeline}, ignore_index=True)
    return df

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3', 'column 4'])

#Backlog Entry 
entry = Entry('column 1', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text')

#Doing Entry
entry2 = Entry('column 2', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text')

#Review Entry
entry3 = Entry('column 3', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text')

#Done Entry
entry4 = Entry('column 4', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text')

#Add each entry to the entries list
entries = [entry, entry2, entry3, entry4]

df = enter_entries(df, entries)

display(df)

Any Advice?
Thank You :)

There are different ways to add a new column, e.g. df..insert..Other ways can be found easy by a search engine in the web.

consider reading this before using ._append

Hi @Hermann12, I am not trying to add a new column I am sorting entries into pre-existing columns

First we create a dummy class to holds data:
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd

@dataclass
class Entry:
    column: str
    task: str = "task"
    desc: str = "description"
    member: str = "member"
    timeline: str = "timeline"

We create some synthetic entries:
entries = [Entry("Col-1"), Entry("Col-2"), Entry("Col-3"), Entry("Col-4")]

Now it is sufficient to iterate through entries and their attribute to update the dataframe:
def append_entries(entries, frame=None):
    frame = frame or pd.DataFrame()
    for entry in entries:
        col = entry.column
        for key in entry.__dict__:
            if key != "column":
                frame.loc[key, col] = entry.__dict__[key]
    return frame

Another alternative, probably more efficient and pandas friendly:
def append_entries(entries, frame=None):
    frame = frame or pd.DataFrame()
    for entry in entries:
        series = pd.Series(entry.__dict__)
        frame[entry.column] = series
    frame = frame.drop("column", axis=0)
    return frame

Both solution return the desired dataframe:
append_entries(entries)

                Col-1        Col-2        Col-3        Col-4
task             task         task         task         task
desc      description  description  description  description
member         member       member       member       member
timeline     timeline     timeline     timeline     timeline

